# Generated web service by WSDL, and different WSDL type

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

I received from the client WSDL file and generated abstract class using wsdl.exe, width all web service methods.

I add generated file to my project and override all methods. When I run web service, and watch WSDL file I see problem:

Client WSDL:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" 
name="getFactResult" type="tns:Fact"/>
```

My web service WSDL:

```
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="getFactResult" 
type="tns:ArrayOfFact"/>
```

My method getFactResult return Fact[]. I don't know where is a problem. Why my WSDL file is different than the client WSDL.

Comment: These are different methods  `getFacultiesResult` vs `getFactResult` so what is the problem?

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake. I corrected it.